# Invoking Update Operation without actually updating fields

Tags: apex

I have written a new WF field update for a CaseLogs__c.

This field update will fire whenever the record is created or edited.

This field update obviously will not fire for records which currently exist in the system but which are not updated.

So I am thinking of doing a mass update via code like this

```
List<CaseLogs__c> cl_list = new List<CaseLogs__c>();

for(CaseLogs__c c :[SELECT ID,Preview__c FROM CaseLogs_c WHERE Preview ='' LIMIT 10000])
{    
cl_list.add(c);    

}    
update cl_list;
```

Because of DML Limit I will be doing in batches of 10000 (via anonymous apex).

Will this work ?.

Will the above approach cause my WF field update to trigger ?.

Since I will be doing it in our instance which has like 28k records I wanna check with folks here before I actually do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the trigger criteria is correct (triggers on every edit), the rule will work without performing any other update to the records. By the way, you don't need to write all that code you wrote. Here's the equivalent code:

```
update [SELECT Id FROM CaseLogs__c WHERE Preview__c = '' LIMIT 10000];
```